# How to install dummy data in typo3 6.2.14?

Tags: typo3

I could not find dummy package of typo3. How to install the dummy data? I am able to install normal but could not find any sample dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dummy package was abandoned some time ago. You automatically get a minimal database and all necessary files after doing the install process (see `INSTALL.md` file).

However, with TYPO3 6.0, "distributions" were introduced, especially the Introduction Package. You can download these in the extension manager, there is an option for getting the list oft distributions and installing them.

Of course you need to make sure you have the right to use these distributions in live sites - I know that at least the introduction package has some restrictions in that place.